# Mouse Spin alternative

Tags: etymology

I have researched this for some time and the only answers I can find are with reference to : "Why is a mouse when it spins" and refers to a steam engine.
Here's my take: Since I can remember, and I was born in 1951, my grandmother would ask,"Why does a mouse the more he spins?" And, the answer was,"Because the faster, he spins the most." I was told that both the question and the answer are grammatically correct. The question: why is the mouse spinning more times round (more revolutions).  The answer: He is spinning faster so he spins more revolutions.  I have not been able to trace how this version originated.

Comment: Also see *[Origin of “Why is a mouse when it spins?” riddle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188235/)*

Comment: I’ve never heard of this riddle before, but I have to say that regardless of its apparent legitimacy as a riddle, I find both the question and the answer totally ungrammatical and nonsensical, just random strings of words that do not combine to make any kind of meaningful or grammatical sentence. I have to assume that is a deliberate part of the riddle.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - It took some thought, but I arrived at a different parse. In the same way one could respond to:  “Why does the mouse eat at night?” with “[I don’t know] Why *does* he at night?”.    Maybe the question was: “Why does a mouse squeak the more he spins?”  ->  Dunno, why *does* a mouse the more he spins?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet See the linked question.